# The size of each sky

Tags: hadith, fiqh, hadith-interpretation, science, universe

Does such a hadith (asar) exist among the Sunnis? Is he trustworthy?

" The size of the earth compared to the first heaven is like the size of a ring in a desert; the size of the first heaven compared to the second is like the size of a ring in a desert, and so on, until the seventh heaven. The size of the seventh heaven compared to the Kursi of Allah is like a ring in a desert, and the size of the Kursi compared to the Throne is likewise".

Comment: What is this? A claim? A statement? ... could you provide a source?

Comment: I want to know if this hadeeth or asar is authentic.

I once heard these words, but I do not know the source. These words were quoted without a source.

Comment: I hope I explained the situation

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. You can refer to this hadith:

> It was narrated that Ibn Mas’ood said: Between the first heaven and the one above it is (a distance of) five hundred years. Between each of the heavens is (a distance of) five hundred years. Between the seventh heaven and the Kursiy is (a distance of) five hundred years. Between the Kursiy and the water is (a distance of) five hundred years, and the Throne is above the water. ALLAAH (Glory Be To HIM) is above the Throne, and nothing whatsoever of your deeds is hidden from Him. (narrated by Ibn Khuzaymah in al-Tawheed, p. 105; by al-Bayhaqi in al-Asmaa’ wa’l-Sifaat, p. 401). This report was classed as saheeh by Ibn al-Qayyim in Ijtimaa’ al-Juyoosh al-Islamiyah, p. 100; by al-Dhahabi in al-‘Uluw, p. 64).

Answer (score 0):

This hadith has been narrated from the Prophet, peace and blessings of God be upon him, in Al-Kafi, Volume 8, Page 153.

The good thing about this hadith is that so far the observed shape of our universe is circular and elliptical, and most of our galaxies and the Milky Way are also circular, and according to some physicists, black holes may be cuts in space and Time is, and black holes are usually elliptical ways of traveling between these worlds.
Another point of the hadith of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) can be a proof of the legitimacy of the night of Ascension because exactly the shape of the world view is similar to scientific findings and the shape of the Milky Way galaxy and the described shape of the elliptical and circular world correspond to today's scientific observations And this accurate description indicates and confirms that when man did not have any telescopes and spaceships to observe space and the shape of space, and on the night that the Holy Prophet (PBUH) ascended to the top, they all saw the greatness of the universe.

Desert can also mean a vacuum or distances between stars, which is like a dry and empty desert.

http://mojezatelmiquran.ir/1399/06/16/%D8%B9%D8%B8%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%87%D8%B3%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%B5-%D9%88-%D8%A7/

Comment: Ok, do Sunnis have such a hadith?

And I did not understand how it is connected with science.