# i want to know about reference of hadith about the skys in which there is zikar of 7 skys

Tags: reference-request

please share referance of hadith on your web at this link [The size of each sky](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/74882/the-size-of-each-sky)

Answer (score -1):

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

This site goes into details regarding the specific words of the size of the earth compared to the first heaven, etc. here

https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/340636/size-of-each-heaven-compared-to-one-above-it

However, there is a narration that states the following:

> Abu Dharr al-Ghifāri (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet (may Allah's peace and blessings be upon him) said: "The Kursi in comparison to the Throne is only like an iron ring thrown in a desert on earth."  Sahih/Authentic. - [Ibn Abi Shaybah in Al-‘Arsh]